# I am getting error "Restoring from checkpoint failed." while training tensorflow estimator api on AI-platform(ml-engine)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to do hyperparameter tuning on ai-engine for DNN regressor using tensorflow estimator api. But after submitting the job, it shows that job is failed and I get this error in job details.

Can someone help?

```
Hyperparameter Tuning Trial #1 Failed before any other successful trials were completed. The failed trial had parameters: learning_rate=0.0019937718716419557, num-layers=2, first-layer-size=148, scale-factor=0.7910729020312588, .  The trial's error message was: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    [...]
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 507, in _build_internal
      restore_sequentially, reshape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 385, in _AddShardedRestoreOps
      name="restore_shard"))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 332, in _AddRestoreOps
      restore_sequentially)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 580, in bulk_restore
      return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1572, in restore_v2
      name=name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
      op_def=op_def)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3300, in create_op
      op_def=op_def)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1801, in __init__
      self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

  InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a mismatch between the current graph and the graph from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

  tensor_name = dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias; shape in shape_and_slice spec [148] does not match the shape stored in checkpoint: [117]
     [[node save/RestoreV2_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py:1403) ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the same output directory for all the trials, and so trial#1 is trying to read trial#2 checkpoint (perhaps because it is the latest one in the directory) and failing because the architecture is different

Make sure to use a different output directory for each hyperparam training run. There are two ways you do this:

1. Use the --job-dir as the output directory.
2. Append a hyperparam trial number to the output directory you are using now:

   output_dir = os.path.join( output_dir, json.loads( os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG', '{}') ).get('task', {}).get('trial', '') )